# Pass two functions to map

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to pass two functions and an iterable object in map

```
test_code = map(get_repo_info, repo_page)

def get_repo_info(data):
  print data['id'], data['full_name']

def repo_page():
   ...some code....
   returns a list of dictionaries that I map over in the map function

def write_to_csv():
   csv_open = open('test.csv', 'wb')
   csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_open)
   return csv_writer
```

In the `get_repo_info()` function I want to write everything to a csv file. Instead of printing out each line, I want to write each line to a csv row

I want it to look something like this

```
def get_repo_info(data, csv_writer):
  csv_writer.writerow([data['id'], data['full_name']])
```

And the `map` function would look something like this

```
map(get_repo_info, repo_page())
```

However, I can't figure out how to pass `get_repo_info()` the second argument of `csv_writer` in the `map` function, since the function used by `map` is only passed one argument at a time, not two.

Comment: `map(get_repo_info, repo_page())`?

Comment: So you want to use `get_repo_info()` as the function in a `map` statement, but the problem is that functions in `map` should only take one argument (a single item from the list) and `get_repo_info()` takes two as it's currently written. I edited your question to clarify this.

Comment: This isn't something that calls for `map`.  map is for 1:1 transforming each element of an iterable into something else.  You're just feeding each element into a `csv.writer` - just use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_repo_info(data):
  print data['id'], data['full_name']

def repo_page():
   return [{"id":"bar","full_name":"foobar"}]


test_code = map(get_repo_info, repo_page()) # call the method
bar foobar
```

You could call map in your `write_to_csv`:

```
def get_repo_info():
    map(write_to_csv,[[[data['id'], data['full_name']] for data in repo_page()]])

def repo_page():
    return [{"id": "bar", "full_name": "foobar"}, {"id": "bar1", "full_name": "foobar1"}]

def write_to_csv(data):
    csv_open = open('test.csv', 'wb')
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_open)
    csv_writer.writerows(data)
get_repo_info()
```

This writes:

```
 bar,foobar
 bar1,foobar1
```

to your csv file.

But using a for loop would achieve the same:

```
def write_to_csv(data):
   csv_open = open('test.csv', 'wb')
   csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_open)
   csv_writer.writerows([[data['id'], data['full_name']] for data in repo_page()])
```

Comment: But how does it get written to csv?

Comment: @TheSoundDefense, the OP's code was not using `repo_page()` so the second arg would not support iteration, that is what I thought he/she was talking about

Answer (score 0):

I just broke it out into a separate function

```
test_code = map(get_repo_info, repo_page)

def get_repo_info(data):
  return (data['id'], data['full_name'])

def repo_page():
   ...some code....
   returns a list of dictionaries that I map over in the map function

def write_to_csv():
   csv_open = open('test.csv', 'wb')
   csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_open)
   return csv_writer

some_info = get_repo_info(data)
csv_writing = write_to_csv()
csv_writing.writerow(some_info)
```